# How to split a json array

Tags: java, json

Well I got this code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONObject profiles = new JSONObject();
        profiles.put("Name", "Roger");
        profiles.put("Age", "Twenty");

        try {
            File profiles_file = new File("D:\\profiles.txt");
            profiles_file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(profiles_file);
            fileWriter.write(profiles.toJSONString());
            fileWriter.flush();
            System.out.print(profiles);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the code, the file gets this data:

> {"Age":"Twenty","Name":"Roger"}

I got a problem with that tho, I would like to know how I could insert the data in this format:

> [ { Age:"Twenty", Name:"Roger" } ]

and if i inserted 2 times data (with the proper changes in the code (append)) i would like to get this:

> [ { Age:"Twenty", Name:"Roger" },
>
> { Age:"Twenty", Name:"Roger" } ]

Thank your in advance,
NearDaniel.

Comment: do you know what a json array is?

Comment: I have some clues

Comment: Put the array intead of the String.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? If you did, you would probably see the fairly obvious class named `JSONArray`. I wonder what it does...

Comment: Cant u just explain?

Comment: Well I could, but is your time more important than mine?

Comment: look @rmlan i just want some help, that why im here. if u dont want to waste your time its fine, im not judging. just dont mock those u dont read the documentation..

Comment: You just summed up why this is a bad question and should be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray profiles = new JSONArray();

JSONObject profile1 = new JSONObject();
profile1.put("Name", "Roger");
profile1.put("Age", "Twenty");

JSONObject profile2 = new JSONObject();
profile2.put("Name", "Roger");
profile2.put("Age", "Twenty");

profiles.add(profile1);
profiles.add(profile2);
```